# Need guidance with a bash script to check log files in a certain directory for a certain string

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to preface this with I am a complete noob with scripting. So I have a situation where I need to manually look for a phone number that could live in one of hundreds of files.

so the logs live in the following directory.

/actlogs/sbclogger_archive

The logs file names are in directories numbered 01-31 inside of that directory and all the files are zipped.

Inside of those numbered directories are tons of files but the only ones I want to search are "sipd.logthenthedate.gz" and "sipmsg.logthenthedate.gz".

So I need to look in all the files in the following directory.
"/actlogs/sbclogger_archive"

Which has 31 directories labeled "01-31"

Then in each 01-31 there is hundreds of files the only ones I want to look are are "sipd.logthenthedate.gz" and "sipmsg.logthenthedate.gz".

The script I am using is below, please let me know what I could do to make this work.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter a phone number: " text
read -p "Enter directory of log file's, Hint it should be /actlogs/sbclogger_archive: " directory

#arr=( $(find $directory -type f -exec grep -l "$text" {} \; | sort -r) )
#find $directory -type f -exec grep -qe "$text" {} \; -exec bash -c '

file=$(find $directory -type f -name 'sipd.log*' -exec grep -qe "$text" {} \; -exec bash -c 'select f; do echo $f; break; done' find-sh {} +;)

if [ -z "$file" ]; then
    echo "No matches found."
else
    echo "select tool:"
    tools=("nano" "less" "vim" "quit")
    select tool in "${tools[@]}"
    do
        case $tool in
            "quit")
                break
                ;;
            *)
                $tool $file
                break
                ;;
        esac
    done
fi
```

Comment: Don't prompt for the tool to use.  Just do: `${EDITOR-vi} "$file"`.  This allows the user to indicate their preferred tool in the EDITOR environment variable, and defaults to `vi` if they have not set a value.  This is conventional behavior.

Comment: Thank you, Once I get the functionality fixed i will def do that.

Comment: I do not understand. `has 31 files labled "01-31"` `n each 01-31 there is hundreds of files ` - files can't have files. Directories can have files. You want `zgrep -l --include 'sipd.log*' "$text" *`? How are the files named? `o make this work` - what should the result be? What the inputs are?

Comment: Hello and thank you for pointing that out I have corrected with an edit. The files inside of the directories "01-31" look like this "sipd.log_10.109.999.999_2020_036_12_00_01.gz". I also need something that will look in all the directories "01-31" but only look in the files named "sipd.logxxxx.gz" and "sipmsg.logxxxx.gz" because there are so many files in the 01-31 directories it would take forever to go through the whole directory without only looking in the files where the string would live.

Comment: So you want `zgrep -rl --include 'simpd.log*.gz' "$test" {01..31}`? Please read `grep` documentation, it has many options.

Comment: Thank you I am going to check it out!

Answer (score 1):

This would give you the list of files matching:

```
find \( -name 'sipd.log[0-9]*.gz' -o -name 'sipmsg.log[0-9]*.gz' \) \
     -exec sh -c 'gunzip -c {}| grep -m1 -q 888333' \; -print

./18/sipd.log20200118.gz
./7/sipd.log20200107.gz
```

Note: `-m1` tells grep to stop after first match, since you need only the file name in this case, it's enough.

If you have `zgrep`, you can shorten it to:

```
find \( -name 'sipd.log[0-9]*.gz' -o -name 'sipmsg.log[0-9]*.gz' \) \
     -exec zgrep -l '888333' {} \;

./18/sipd.log20200118.gz
./7/sipd.log20200107.gz
```

Also, some of the tools you are suggesting do not support gzip files (`nano` and some variants of `less` for example). In which case you might need to decompress the file and compress it again when done.

And, you might want to consider a loop if you want to "quit". Feeding the file list to the tool doesn't make sense.

**Note:** AFAIK [zgrep](https://www.unix.com/man-page/v7/1/zgrep/) doesn't do recursive:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> Zgrep  invokes  grep  on  compressed  or  gzipped  files.   These  grep    options  will  cause  zgrep  to  terminate  with  an 
>   error  code:
>          (-[d**rR**zZ]|--di*|--exc*|**--inc***|--rec*|--nu*).  All other options specified are passed directly to grep.  If no file is specified,  then
>   the
>          standard input is decompressed if necessary and fed to grep.  Otherwise the given files are uncompressed if necessary and fed to
>   grep.

so `zgrep -rl "$text" "$directory"` or `zgrep -rl --include 'simpd.log*.gz' "$test" {01..31}` won't work except if you have a special `zgrep`

Comment: You got me going in a great direction, thank you so much. I tried to up vote you but my account does not have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: @Dale what is missing for you to accept this answer ?

Answer (score -1):

As you must unzip before using your tool, i would divide the problem in two blocks.
Firstly, i would expand the paths you need (looking under `<directory>` for the phone `<text>`), and then iterate to apply the tool (because some tools like `vim` or `nano` cannot be piped).
Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#...
# text/directory input stuff
#...
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)
trap 'rm -rf ${tmpdir}' EXIT

while IFS= read -r file; do
  unzipped=${tmpdir}/$(basename "${file}" .gz)
  gunzip -c "${file}" > "${unzipped}"
  ${tool} "${unzipped}"
done < <(zgrep -lw "${text}" "${directory}"/{01..31}/{sipd.logthenthedate.gz,sipmsg.logthenthedate.gz} 2>/dev/null)
```

Above is the proposed invert-form by Charles Duffy following this [Bash FAQ](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

If you prefer to iterate an array, you could build in this way:

```
# shellcheck disable=SC2207
files=( $(zgrep -lw "${text}" "${directory}"/{01..31}/{sipd.logthenthedate.gz,sipmsg.logthenthedate.gz} 2>/dev/null) )

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
# etc.
```

as in our particular case, the files to match have no spaces in their names and shellcheck warning is not so important (hidden above).

BRs

Comment: This is missing quotes in lots of places. Unquoted, `${files[@]}` is exactly the same as `${files[*]}`, which is to say, prone to unwanted string-splitting and glob expansion. `files=( $(...) )` is likewise buggy; see [BashPitfalls #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29).

Comment: ...I'd generally suggest running the whole thing through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds.

Comment: Thank u, i will use the shellcheck from now on (on stackoverflow), i was a little lazy

Comment: Unfortunately, shellcheck isn't enough on its own (at least, not without reading the wiki page linked for each warning) -- see the BashPitfalls link for a way to fix the array assignment that still keeps it as an array assignment. With the narrow change now applied, there's only one entry in the files array.

Comment: i think, the best solution is to remove the zgrep surrounding quotes, as you know that only two files (sipd.logthenthedate.gz and sipmsg.logthenthedate.gz) are being retrieved and they miss spaces in its names. I will put the shellcheck exception and will edit the answer again. Please, suggest a better solution and thank you for your advice.

Comment: @charles-duffy, could you check my last recipe added to the answer ? I think, using `read` is better and smart.

Comment: So, for the first approach, `readarray -t files < <(zgrep -lw ...)` will read into an array

Comment: for the second, a `while read` loop is perfectly reasonable, but it's better to invert it as described in [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) so variables set inside the loop persist after it exits. Also, note that you want `while IFS= read -r file; do` to avoid stripping leading and trailing whitespace or corrupting filenames that have literal backslashes in them.